# Parametrized Style within UserControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles

I used [this MSDN tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2007/02/01/parameterizedtemplates.aspx) to create an eye candy look for all the `Button` controls of my window, and that worked fine.

To make it even more reusable, I tried to put all in a UserControl: I created a ImageButton UC, then I encapsulated all that `<Style>` from `<Window.Resources>` to `<UserControl.Resources>`.

Then I changed my Button instances in XAML, from:

`<Button Tag="Face.jpg" Content="Foo" />`

To:

`<uc:ImageButton Tag="Face.jpg" Content="Foo" />`

And the style stopped being applied.

Here's the UC code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GDTI.UI.Main.View.UserControls.ImageButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="250" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

        <Setter Property="Background" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" Opacity="0.4" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Tag,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                              FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType='Button'}}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Content,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                       FindAncestor,
                                       AncestorType='Button'}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Button/>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Gaaahhh! You have custom user control and you still use the `Tag` property? (Also it's hard to divine where the problem is in that code you did not post)

Comment: The next step was to avoid the `Tag` property, that's why I was going to use UCs... posting the code right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindings in the button-style target properties on the button, which no longer has the properties set. You need to forward those to the `UserControl` if you want to retain the style's integrity:

```
<!-- Inside UserControl declaration -->
<Button Content="{Binding Caption, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        Tag="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Where `Caption` and `ImageSource` should be new [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) defined on the UserControl (in code-behind).

Note that you can never bind to `Content` in a `UserControl` (hence the `Caption` property), here the `Button` itself **is** the `Content` of the `UserControl`.

Alternatively you could directly change the targeting in the style by changing the `AncestorType` to `UserControl` which bypasses the `Button`. Binding beyond the templated control is not exactly good practice but your are still inside the `UserControl` so it may be forgivable.

Either way this is a bit hacky and it might be better to inherit from `Button` instead.